# drawRect and addSubview: custom drawing affects which views?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

If I have a custom subclass of `UIView` that implements `drawRect` and controller methods use `addSubview` to create a view hierarchy in this custom view, how does `drawRect` interact with these subviews? Does it recreate the entire subclass's view hierarchy from scratch and remove any existing subviews? Or does it ignore subviews and only redraw a particular view/subview?

Would it be acceptable to programmatically add and remove subviews within `drawRect`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`drawRect` is meant to be **only** for drawing your content in the view.

Whether it draws the entire view or part of it: It depends on your implementation. If you want to do any optimization is a good idea to check when your view calls `drawRect` and adjust the code accordingly (maybe you want to update only one part of the view, maybe you don't want to draw all the times, etc). It depends on your needs

I don't think is a good idea to add/remove subviews within `drawRect` because this method will be called in several situations and I dare to say that is NOT what you want :)

Instead, you could try something like this:

```
[myView addSubview:aSubview];
[myView setNeedsDisplay];
//or calculate the needed display rect by yourself and then
[myView setNeedsDisplayInRect:aRect];
```

Comment: my confusion is about which of your subviews in a custom uiview class will actually be affected by `drawRect`? `setNeedsdisplay` does not specify a particular view... so will it redraw any and all subviews, if they are on top of each other?

Answer (score 5):

`-drawRect:` doesn't interact with subviews.  It draws whatever the view it's sent to wants  to draw in the rect it's given.

> Would it be acceptable to programmatically add and remove subviews within drawRect?

**NO.**  `-drawRect:` is for drawing, not for manipulating the view hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not quite clear which view would be updated with `setNeedsDisplay` since you are not specifying a particular view.

Comment: -setNeedsDisplay is always sent to a view.

Comment: Ah, so when you say `[someView setNeedsDisplay]` it will not affect any subviews of that view, which instead can be redrawn by addressing them directly like `[someView.subview setNeedsDisplay]`, correct?

Comment: Why is it an issue when the subviews are redrawn?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am merely trying to understand how this works and if it is wise to add subviews to a custom drawing object. in my program, i'm trying to decide where to put my subview, etc and this question came up and i couldn't really find any exacting info on the relationship of a custom drawing object with its subviews with regards to drawRect.

Comment: In my program, I tried calling `[self addSubview: ...]` from a method that I was calling from `drawRect`. This resulted into the view trying to update its appearance again and another call to `drawRect`... and an infinite loop.