# Which method is the right one to add subview of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LCHButton.h"

@interface ParentView: UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) LCHButton *addStarButton;
@end
```

In which method should I put `[self addSubview:self.addStarButton];`?

Comment: You can add `subView` in `init` method or make a function `-(void)setUpUI` and add all `subView` in this method, Call this function at last when everything is done. Means you should add `subView` at once no matter where you are adding.

Answer (score 2):

Few things you should correct for best coding practice:

1. Import `LCHButton` inside `ParentView.m` to avoid dependency warnings.
2. Same for the property, add it inside `ParentView.m` under your class extension. Things you don't need to access globally should be defined as locally.

e.g.

```
@Interface ParentView ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) LCHButton *addStarButton;
@end
```

3. Answer to your question:

> In `init` or `initWithFrame:` method of your `ParentView` you can it.

e.g.

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self) {
        [self addSubview:self.addStarButton];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  But someone told me that it's not good to use getter or setter in  init method.

Comment: @ustbyjs FYI, `addSubview` is not a getter or setter method.

Comment: I know But self.addStarButton is a getter method and I don't want to use _addStarButton  because I use lazy loading  to init addStarButton

Comment: @ustbyjs, as long as you're using it inside `.m` it won't be accessible from other class.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to add the subview. Mostly the good practice is to add it in viewDidLoad method so it's only added once. You can add it in viewWillAppear too but remember to remove it in viewDidDisappear, else you will have a lot of subviews.

Comment: Thank you! But I want do it in  Parentview Class. which method of the Parentview Class can I put  "[self addSubview:self.addStarButton]" in ?

Comment: Oh, so you want to add an UIView inside another UIView class?  According to this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225789/drawrect-and-addsubview-custom-drawing-affects-which-views it is not recommended to do so, maybe you can try to explain what you want to acheive

Comment: yes ! I want to add an UIView inside another UIView class and the childView is  parentView's property. And I was told that it is not good to use getter or setter in init . So I want to know if there's another method to put in the code